# Unset css property in css. Is it possible?

Tags: html, css, dom, display

Unset css property in css. Is it possible?

Let me explain the problem with the css code.

We have two classes at hand: `.whenRolledUp` and `.whenRolledDown`.

I want my element to comply with the following rules:

1 When an **element** with `.whenRolledUp` class is positioned in DOM hierarchy and have an element with a class `.rolledDown` somewhere above itself in the hierarchy I would like to disable the **element**. Otherwise, I would like to do nothing to the display of the **element**. I am able to satisfy this with the help of this css:

```
.rolledDown .whenRolledUp {
    display: none;
}
```

2 When an **element** with `.whenRolledDown` class is positioned in DOM hierarchy and have an element with a class `.rolledDown` somewhere above itself in the hierarchy I would like to do nothing to the display of  **element**. Otherwise, I would like to have display: none for the **element**. I am able to satisfy the second part using this:

```
.whenRolledDown {
    display: none;
}
```

But here is the catch. I can not satisfy the first part by just using this:

```
.rolledDown .whenRolledDown {
    display: block;
}
```

Because here I am actually setting the display to block, while it may have a different value without this css.

It seems like the problem is impossible to solve with only css. Is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`display: unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset):

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it
>   inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not.

```js
function add() {
  document.querySelector('.target').classList.add('rolledDown');
}
```

```css
.whenRolledUp {
    display: none;
}

.rolledDown .whenRolledUp {
    display: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <div class="whenRolledUp">whenRolledDown</div>
</div>

<button onClick="add()">Add rolledDown</button>
```